# Rider got "There was no build tools found" error

Tags: asp.net-core, jetbrains-ide, rider

I installed the Jetbrains Rider IDE EAP 12 (163.6834) in macOS, and create a new project of asp.net core mvc, but I got a error when I press Run button as below, I guess this is because my System toolset is empty in Preferences as screenshot, but I dont' know how to solve it.[image: my System toolset is empty in Preferences]

```
— EXCEPTION #1/2 [InvalidOperationException]
Message = “There was no build tools found”
ExceptionPath = Root.InnerException
ClassName = System.InvalidOperationException
HResult = COR_E_INVALIDOPERATION=80131509
Source = JetBrains.Platform.ProjectModel.Host
StackTraceString = “
at JetBrains.ProjectModel.ProjectsHost.MsBuild.MsBuildSessionHolder.CreateSession () [0x00036] in <d56975ff7c7b45ca9ece62fa812698e6>:0 
    at JetBrains.ProjectModel.ProjectsHost.MsBuild.MsBuildSessionHolder.get_Session () [0x0000a] in <d56975ff7c7b45ca9ece62fa812698e6>:0 
    at JetBrains.ReSharper.Host.Features.EditProjectProperties.EditProjectProperties.<.ctor>b__0 (JetBrains.DataFlow.Lifetime lt, JetBrains.Rider.Model.EditProjectPropertiesSession editSession) [0x0011a] in <ec4b565dcde946098d9abab7af9373d2>:0 
    at JetBrains.Platform.RdFramework.Util.ReactiveEx+<>c__DisplayClass41[T].<ViewNotNull>b__3 (JetBrains.DataFlow.Lifetime lf, T v) [0x00008] in <1c6833f330ab4917b71044a5ce3ead83>:0 
    at JetBrains.Platform.RdFramework.Util.ReactiveEx+<>c__DisplayClass1 1[T].<View>b__0 (T v) [0x00011] in <1c6833f330ab4917b71044a5ce3ead83>:0 
    at JetBrains.Platform.RdFramework.Util.Signal1[T].Fire0 (System.Action 1[T][] listeners, T value) [0x0000a] in <1c6833f330ab4917b71044a5ce3ead83>:0
”
```

Comment: Did you install the .NET Core runtime/SDK? https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos

Comment: yes, I can run 'dotnet' command in Termnal

Answer (score 2):

Are you a solution .NET Core only or you use mixed xproj and csproj solution? Currently, Rider support to build a mixed solution only on Windows platform with installed VS 2015 and .NET Core VS tools.

Comment: .net core only, I just create a template project from Rider start page.